# Stepper motor quits working after a short while, even though the code still works. (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am running the following code on my Raspberry Pi 4B, using Python 3.7.3:

```
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import math
from watchgod import watch

g=open("/home/pi/Desktop/Int2/DesHeight.txt","r")
DesHeight = g.readline()
DesHeight1=float(DesHeight)
print(DesHeight1)

GPIO.cleanup()

DIR = 20
STEP = 21
CW = 0
CCW = 1
TX_ENC = 15
SPR = 200 # Steps per Rev [CONSTANT]
delay = .001 #Seconds per stepper pulse [CONSTANT]
ratio=24 #gear ratio [CONSTANT]
f = open("height.txt", "r")
y0 = f.readline()
y0 = float(y0)
d=1.25
r=d/2
theta0=y0/(2*math.pi*r)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) # GPIO numbering
GPIO.setup(12,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(12,1) # Turning on the "Enable Input"
GPIO.setup(DIR, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(STEP, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(DIR, CW) # Setting CW Direction
GPIO.setup(TX_ENC, GPIO.IN) # Encoder input setup
GPIO.add_event_detect(TX_ENC, GPIO.BOTH)
Tx = 0

MODE = (16,17,18,19) # GPIO 16 is the standby input. It needs to be high for anything to move
GPIO.setup(MODE,GPIO.OUT)
RESOLUTION = {'Standby':(0,0,0,0),
              'Full':(1,0,0,0),
              'Half':(1,1,0,0),
              '1/4':(1,0,1,0),
              '1/8':(1,1,1,0),
              '1/16':(1,0,0,1),
              '1/32':(1,1,0,1),
              '1/64':(1,0,1,1),
              '1/128':(1,1,1,1)}
GPIO.output(MODE,RESOLUTION['Full'])
ass = (0,0,0,0)
pp = list(ass)
pp[0] = GPIO.input(MODE[0])
pp[1] = GPIO.input(MODE[1])
pp[2] = GPIO.input(MODE[2])
pp[3] = GPIO.input(MODE[3])
ass = tuple(pp)

if(ass == RESOLUTION['Standby']):
    res = 0
elif(ass == RESOLUTION['Full']):
    res = 200
elif(ass == RESOLUTION['Half']):
    res = 400
elif(ass == RESOLUTION['1/4']):
    res = 800
elif(ass == RESOLUTION['1/8']):
    res = 1600
elif(ass == RESOLUTION['1/16']):
    res = 3200
elif(ass == RESOLUTION['1/32']):    
    res = 6400
elif(ass == RESOLUTION['1/64']):
    res=12800
elif(ass == RESOLUTION['1/128']):
    res=25600
else:
    print("Whoops lol")

while(True):
    for changes in watch('/home/pi/Desktop/Int2/DesHeight.txt'):
        g=open("/home/pi/Desktop/Int2/DesHeight.txt","r")
        DesHeight = g.readline()
        DesHeight1=float(DesHeight)
        f = open("height.txt", "r")
        y0 = f.readline()
        y0=float(y0)
        while(abs(y0-DesHeight1)>.001):
            if(y0 < DesHeight1):
                while(y0 < DesHeight1):
                    GPIO.output(DIR,CCW)    
                    GPIO.output(STEP, GPIO.HIGH)
                    sleep(delay)
                    GPIO.output(STEP, GPIO.LOW)
                    sleep(delay)
                    Tx = Tx + 1
                    theta0=theta0+1/res*1/ratio#*1/gearratio
                    y0 = y0+2*5/4*14/15*.9944*math.pi*(1/res*1/ratio)*r
            else:
                while(y0 > DesHeight1):
                   if(y0>0):     
                        GPIO.output(DIR,CW)    
                        GPIO.output(STEP, GPIO.HIGH)
                        sleep(delay)
                        GPIO.output(STEP, GPIO.LOW)
                        sleep(delay)
                        Tx = Tx - 1
                        theta0=theta0-1/res*1/ratio#*1/gearratio
                        y0 = y0-2*5/4*14/15*.9944*math.pi*(1/res*1/ratio)*r
        y0 = str(y0)
        print(y0)
        f.close()
        f = open('height.txt', 'w')
        f.write(y0)
        f.close()
```

Essentially, what I am trying to do is read the height of a machine from a text file, then compare it with the desired height, as written in a separate text file. When the code detects a change in the desired height, it checks to make sure that the actual height and the desired height are within 1/1000 of an inch of each other, and if not, it moves a NEMA-17 motor until this condition is met.

The problem I am encountering is that if this code is left to run for a little bit (usually around 40 seconds) the stepper motor ceases to run when I change the desired height. The code itself runs, taking as long as expected to "move" the motor and also calculating the height and returning to the top of the while loop, but the motor itself remains stagnant. This does not occur if new changes to the desired height file are implemented immediately. I am at a loss as to what this could be and could use some help.

Comment: Can you verify that the outputs of the step and direction pins are toggling like they are supposed to (use an o-scope or logic analyzer)?  What have you done to try and debug this?  Could the stepper driver chip be overheating and shutting down after running for 40 seconds?

Comment: I am rather new to stepper motors and electronics in general, so I had not considered checking it with the oscilloscope; I will give it a look and report back. I doubt that the stepper driver chip is overheating, as I have been running a stress-test code for the last 2 weeks on it, where it moves continuously for 5 minutes on, then 5 minutes of rest. Interestingly, I don't get the issue when I run that code, despite the lengthy wait.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so following the advice of RootTwo, and learning how to use an oscilloscope, I was able to isolate part of the problem and determine a solution. Either the pi or the driver quits supplying a voltage to the motor after about 90 seconds of inactivity. I was not able to find a way to continuously keep the motor at holding torque, but I was able to make it so that the code will reinitialize after a long break by moving the while(True): and watchdog command to the beginning of the code. My problem is technically solved, but my question is yet unanswered: Why does my pi stop giving a signal to the driver board?

Comment: Using the o-scope on the signals between the RPi and the stepper driver should tell you if its the RPi or the driver.  What driver are you using.

Comment: The Toshiba TB67S128FTG